# Joomla 1.5 Stripping &amp;

Tags: html, joomla

Has anyone ever found Joomla 1.5 stripping the & from html especially when adding html via the use of a customer html module ?

an example of some html that I have within a custom html module is :

```
<span style="font-size: 12pt;"> <strong><a href="https://www.feedblitz.com/f/?Sub=869335&amp;cids=1">
```

But when I curl my site I get ..

```
<span style="font-size: 12pt;"> <strong><a href="https://www.feedblitz.com/f/?Sub=869335&cids=1">
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal, with html

```
&amp; = &
```

if you simply create a new html file and write

```
&amp;
```

into it, when you open it you'll just see

```
&
```